# How to create a Combo Chart in iccube Reporting 6?

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

There is the possibility to select a google combo chart in the new iccube 6 reporting. But I am not able to add one bar chart with a line series.

Has anybody got this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### AmChart`s graph configurations

You can use any number of graph configurations you want, and each of it may have it's on type defined in graph configuration's advanced settings.

Take a look at the [Demo Report](https://demo6.iccube.com/icCube/doc/ic3report?name=%2Fshared%2FStackOverflow%2FCombo%20AmChart&ic3demo).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! With Amchart I got it working. But sadly they are blocking the browser while doing a larger query. But still thank you maybe in the future it is also possible with google charts :)